# Can I use all the HTML tags inside a script tag of type javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried placing some of the HTML tags inside a JavaScript tag but its not working.can anyone explain it.

Comment: Define "not working": What do you expect to happen? What tags have you placed there and in what context?: Provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Do you mean doing something like:
`<script type="text/javascript"><p>Hello, World?</p></script>`?

Comment: it seems emacscript 2015, like uses react?

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't. HTML is not Javascript (obviously). Any raw html inside a `<script>` block is simply a syntax error:

```
<script>
    <div>Hi mom!</div> // <-- javascript syntax error

    var foo = '<div>Hi mom!</div>'; // valid javascript.
</script>
```

The second one works because it's **NOT** Html. It's a javascript string that contains some characters that LOOK like html.

The only HTML-ism that's valid inside javascript is the comment opener, `<!--`, which is supported only for historical reasons (to hide JS from browsers which didn't understand/support the `<script>` tag).

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this answer. +1.

Comment: Yes I've tried using some of the HTML tags like header tags they are working well when they are used with out quotes but some tags like </a> are not working <script type="text/javascript">
function display(){
  document.write("<h1 style='color:blue;'>Thank you for submitting your details</h1>");
 
}

Comment: @CodeChandra: then you need to show your code. we can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but if I had to guess, it was because this answer is not considered useful in the context of a question that's about to be closed and probably deleted. Personally if I bothered to answer I'd also mention it's commonplace to change the `type` attribute in order to create HTML templates.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function display(){
  document.write("<h1 style='color:blue;'>Thank you for submitting your details</h1>");
  <a href="www.google.com">click</a>
 
}
</script>

Comment: @CodeChandra — Don't stuff that sort of thing into comments. **Edit** the question. Provide a [MCVE].

Comment: edit your question. don't put code blocks into comments. they're unreadable. And note that your `<a ...</a>` is OUTSIDE of a string. therefore it's bare html inside a script block. your problem is a coding error on YOUR part, and has nothing to do with html. doesn't matter that it's html. you have naked text inside a JS code block. that's illegal JS no matter what you use for the text.

Comment: Then what can I do

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, good explanation. Thanks.

Comment: fix your code. your error is EXACTLY what I posted in my example.